# How to set doubleAction property of NSTableViewCell in Swift?

Tags: cocoa, swift

I am trying to add a double click listener to my `NSTableView` for each cell. Everywhere I searched it seems to be done using a `@selector` and all the source code was in `Objective-C`. I tried to convert that code to `Swift` to assign the `doubleAction` method to my `NSTableView` however it's not working (as my method is not getting called).

```
@IBOutlet var tableView:NSTableView?

override func awakeFromNib() {
        let clSelector:Selector = "dblClk:"

        tableView?.doubleAction = clSelector
    }

    func dblClk(sender:AnyObject){
        println("ran")
    }
```

Also my tableView has custom cells (in case that matters).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was forgetting this:
`tableView?.target = self`

It works perfectly now!

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    table.target = self
    table.doubleAction = #selector(tableViewDoubleAction)
}

@objc func tableViewDoubleAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("row double clicked")
}
```